# Buttons added to list view don't show up

Tags: custom-button, appexchange, button, search-layout

I am trying to install an app (Mass Edit) and make some very simple modifications to my sandbox. I successfully installed the app and have gone into the Object Manager for Contacts and followed the instructions to make the buttons appear - it now looks like this:

[image: screenshot of object manager]

As you can see, the "Mass Edit" and "Mass Update" buttons should appear on the List or Search layouts, like so:

[image: image from app store page showing successful implementation]

However, here is what my Contact page looks like:

[image: my current Contact page]

So the buttons aren't showing up.

I don't think the problem is on the app's end, because it has overwhelming hundreds of positive reviews. Is there another step to this process that I'm missing? Any weird permissions I need to activate?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Have you clicked the down arrow next to "Add to Campaign" to make sure that those functions are not there?

Comment: @DanKowalski sorry for not clarifiying that already, yes I have, this is all that appears: https://i.imgur.com/JU4gBuo.png

Comment: Interesting I was able to get this to work in my dev org. Have you tried using this in a different view?

Comment: @DanKowalski Oho... I tried using Classic earlier and thought I couldn't get it to work but just checked back and it looks like it's running there. Interesting that the same actions didn't get it to show up in Lightning. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: so is your issue resolved? @james

Comment: @James I didn't mean go to classic I meant that you try using another list view on the contact tab.

Comment: @Rao no the issue isn't resolved, I do need the app to work in Lightning  (some of the users aren't savvy enough to navigate classic).

Comment: @DanKowalski my bad! Thanks for the clarification. Sadly it does not appear on any different list views (I tried "all contacts",  "New last week", and "birthdays this month")

Comment: Are you checking on your profile as a system admin or are you checking using a different user with a different profile?

Comment: Go to Setup--> Objects and fields --> Object manager --> Contact--> Search Layouts --> List view (click edit by pulling down the arrow at the right corner) --> see if your button is added to the Selected buttons list. Refresh the browser and give it a few mins for the server to get the latest metadata and let me know if you still dont see the button